# A Record to Set domain.com to IP 1.1.1.1 and domain.com/somecode to IP 2.2.2.2

Tags: domain-name-system

How to set up that following? Traffic for domain.com goes to IP 1.1.1.1. and any traffic for domain.com/code to IP 2.2.2.2.
Is this possible with an A record?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the URL `example.com` and `example.com/code`, DNS only deals with the portion of `example.com`. So no, there is no way to do what you are asking with DNS.

You could do `code.example.com` and have *that* go to a different IP address.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Is there a way to do this with htaccess of any other method you know of?

Comment: It sounds like this is your *real* question. "How can I make two URLs that only differ in the path run on different servers?" There are many different ways to achieve this and it can be done using an `.htaccess` file. Rather than asking further questions in the comments, it's better to either edit your original question or ask a new question.